# Firestore collection group update doc

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Is it possible in Firestore to update a document in a collection group?

For example, if I only have the doc id, can I do something like this:

```
const player = firebase.db.collectionGroup("players").doc(playerId); 
player.update(...);
```

Or do I need the full path to the document in order to update it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code you're showing isn't possible because `collectionGroup()` returns a Query object, and `doc()` isn't a method on that.  You will have to query the collection group to find the document you want, then delete it as a separate operation.  Also note that it's entirely possible for there to be multiple documents with the same ID within a collection group, as the group spans any number of subcollections.

Keep in mind that a query on a collection group *can't filter all of the documents based on document a document ID*.  Typically people get around this by writing the ID of the document in a field of each document, then using that field as a filter on the collection group query.